# Trying to assign user input to elements in a struct but keep getting segmentation-fault 11

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

```
struct Book {
    char *title; 
    char *authors; 
    unsigned int year; 
    unsigned int copies; 
};
```

```
void book_to_add()
{
    struct Book book;
    struct Book *ptrbook = (struct Book*) malloc(sizeof(struct Book));

    printf("Book you would like to add: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", book.title);

    printf("Author of Book: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", book.authors);

    printf("Year book was published: \n");
    scanf("%u", &book.year);

    printf("number of copies: \n ");
    scanf("%u", &book.copies);

    add_book(book);
    free(ptrbook);
}
```

I am quite new to programming and I am unsure what I should do to solve this, I know it might have to do with the pointer elements in the struct.

Comment: Add a space before the `%` in `scanf()` for it to consume optional leading whitespace: `scanf(" %[...]", ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title` and `authors` are uninitialized pointers, you will need to allocate memory for them (***i.e.*** make them point to some valid memory location) if you want to store anything there, ***e.g.***:

```
book.authors = malloc(100);
book.authors = malloc(100);
```

for a buffer able to store 99 character + the null terminator `'\0'`.

---

On that note, make sure to use a size delimiter in `scanf` otherwise there is the chance for buffer overflow, ***e.g***:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", book.title);
scanf(" %99[^\n]", book.authors);
```

for a buffer of 100 characters.